# Magento2 Cart and Checkout page is not working

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, error, console

I am using **Magento 2.3.1**. When entering the **cart** and **checkout page**, the errors appear in the **console log**.
I am trying with an upgrade and a clear cache. but it's not working.
Try with some solution. But still it's not working.

Please, someone help me to figured out.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the setup of the session and cookies value of the admin side?

Comment: we do not write any custom session and cookies. we used the default Magento session.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it in magento 1.9 ? I am having same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have fixed this issue by changing the **vendor** folder with fresh **Magento**. Now Its Working Fine But we have no idea how this issue occurs.

Comment: what to do if I want to fix this issue in magento 1.9 ?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issues, actually i had added some third party extension and that was getting conflicted so i have removed that and i have run the command.
[image]

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade

  php bin/magento setup:di:compile

  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

  php bin/magento cache:clean

  php bin/magento cache:flush

  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US en_CA

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, please run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [<languages>]`. Change `[<languages>]` into your language, for example: en_US, en_GB,..etc

Comment: we try this solution. But still, an error occurs.